# Google maps not rendering despite using API key

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm writing code for an android application and my maps activity looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0F2P.png)

I have a `google_maps_api.xml` in `/res/values`, its content is

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
         MYKEY
    </string>
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` file looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities. ..." />

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities. ..."
            android:label="..." />

        <activity android:name=".Activities. ...">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I've also made sure to have `Google Maps Android API` enabled for the project I generated the API key in `console.developers.google.com`.

Is there I'm potentially missing?

**EDIT** I've tried creating a new google maps project, generated a new key, same result with the map (it doesn't work). Any clue what I could be missing? I've also added the SHA-1 and package name for key restriction

Comment: Did you set an Android app restriction on the API key? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#key-std-details

Comment: [Nope](https://i.imgur.com/WNgAVMY.png)

Comment: You must set a restriction according to the official documentation.

Comment: I've set the restriction for an android app, providing my SHA key and package name for the most recent key and deleted the others, still not working for some reason...

Comment: @xomena see the edit please

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `strings.xml` your API key , something like this:

```
<string name="google_maps_key">your_key</string>
```

If not work :

Try change your activity to this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
 SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
 }
 @Override
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
 mMap = googleMap;
 // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
 LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
 }
}
```

and xml file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 tools:context="com.example.app.MapsActivity"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried both your recommendation in a new google maps project and that still didn't work

Comment: I don't know , it's should, work probably you have some problem at server. Maybe try do this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start step by step .

Comment: @Andrei And try to start app in real device , because emulator sometimes have problems with google services.